# Tomcat connection pool MBeans don't always show up in scan

Tags: tomcat, jdbc, connection-pooling, jmx

I'm using some code to monitor my Tomcat (9) connection pools.  However, when I scan for the Datasource MBeans, the returned results are not consistent.  Does anyone have an explanation for why this might be?

Sometimes I get three MBeans (Datasource + connection pool + connection):

```
NAME: Catalina:type=DataSource,host=localhost,context=/,class=javax.sql.DataSource,name="jdbc/evote",connectionpool=connections,connection=1
DESC: Information on the management interface of the MBean
CLAS: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.PoolableConnection

NAME: Catalina:type=DataSource,host=localhost,context=/,class=javax.sql.DataSource,name="jdbc/evote"
DESC: null
CLAS: org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean

NAME: Catalina:type=DataSource,host=localhost,context=/,class=javax.sql.DataSource,name="jdbc/evote",connectionpool=connections
DESC: Information on the management interface of the MBean
CLAS: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool
```

But at other times, the connection pool ones don't appear in the scan. I only get the simple Datasource one:

```
NAME: Catalina:type=DataSource,host=localhost,context=/,class=javax.sql.DataSource,name="jdbc/evote"
DESC: null
CLAS: org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean
```

Why would the connection pool MBean(s) not be always available?

Comment: Which (minor) version of Tomcat 9.0 are you using? The underlying version of `tomcat-dbcp.jar` has changed between minor revisions.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz It's 9.0.30 running in Eclipse. Haven't tested on a standalone Tomcat yet tho.  I've discovered the problem occurs after Eclipse restarts Tomcat.  If I query the MBeans before any connection is created, no connection pool bean is returned.  My current workaround is to create a dummy connection before accessing the MBeans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noticed in your comment, the MBean corresponding to the connection pool is created only after `getConnection` is called for the first time.

However, since [DBCP 2.8.0](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/changes-report.html#a2.8.0), which is shipped with [Tomcat 9.0.38](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/changelog.html#Tomcat_9.0.38_(markt)/Other) and later, you have an action `start()` on the `BasicDataSourceMXBean`, which allows you to create the pool without creating any connections.